# Selenium testing with HTML Selenese

Tags: selenium

I am doing some testing in Selenium using the selenium maven plugin and HTML selenese scripts. 
Everything works pretty well except for this scenario I have: 
I am clicking on a submit button and it takes me to a redirect url. The server for that URL is not running but the web service that redirect the URL create a code query parameter and add it to the redirect URL. 
I want to be able to click submit and use storeLocation selenese command to extract the redirect url and extract that code parameter. When I use clickAndWait, the redirect happens but the test fails because the page tries to load and eventually the maven build. When I use just click command, the test passes, but the  page doesn't load and storeLocation doesn't contain the value of the redirect url I need with the code parameter. 
Anyone know how to get selenium to click and wait but IGNORE the fact that the page will not load?
I think it needs to involve some javascript and maybe the use of waitForCondition command but I can't find any example of it being done. 
basically, the redirect URL has no server running it, but my service create a token param that I need to extract from and pass it to another test case

Comment: Why have you not accepted answers provided to your previously asked questions?

Comment: it seems that you can only accept question within 15 mins of asking it and I ask then go on and try to continue solving my questions.

Comment: Or maybe i just don't know how to accept answers

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in HTML Selenese since it was made only to serve to basic cases. In any programming language it would be pretty trivial. If you're using Selenium IDE, export the script to any language of your preference and we'll gladly help from there. ... (or maybe you could run a javascript on it, huh)

Comment: I solved my issue, after clicking on my submit button, (use the click command), I used waitForLocation command and gave it the pattern of the url i am expecting at that location.

Comment: works great, should have read the docs more rigourously

Answer (score 0):

Is the page load timing out? If so you could increase the default timeout (should be 30 seconds though) or you can use the click event, and then do a waitForLocation to match the new URL (with redirect parameter) you want. This will give you another wait for (like click and wait) of 30 seconds. But you can also add a pause command between the click and the wait for to extend your time for the page to load without touching the default time out.